# IOException when compressing HDFS files

Tags: hadoop, gzip, codec

I would like to compress currently existing files in HDFS and delete the uncompressed files. Here is the code, but it errors out with an IOException. Any pointers on why this is happening?

```
CompressionCodecFactory ccf = new CompressionCodecFactory(conf);
CompressionCodec codec = ccf.getCodecByClassName(GzipCodec.class.getName());                        
InputStream inpStrm = codec.createInputStream(fs.open(infoFilePath));
OutputStream compressedOutputSream = codec.createOutputStream(fs.create( new Path( infoFile + "." + codec.getDefaultExtension()) ));

IOUtils.copyBytes(inpStrm, compressedOutputSream, conf);
```

But it errors out with an IOException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.inflateBytesDirect(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.decompress(ZlibDecompressor.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:85)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Comment: Did you have any luck finding the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly some files that look like compressed are not compressed in addition to your newly created files. I had this problem, when files with .gz extension were plain text files. Different Hadoop versions handle this differently. Apparently, file name get's involved.